# Can a child node be assigned back to its parent node in tree structure?

Tags: data-structures, nlp, topic-modeling, topology, search-tree

As title, I'm currently trying to build a tree structure to take my topics/definitions and their related topics/definition into a tree for traversal and further analysis. The data look like this:

```
VR(root)
|____electric vehicle
    |____electric car
        |____electric vehicle
        |____chain link
        |____marketing automation
    |____laser cutting
        |____performance marketing
        |____electric vehicle
        |____dental bonding
    |____performance marketing
        |____marketing automation
        |____call-tracking software
        |____PaaS
```

Problems are:

(1)some topics are related back to other parent topics
(2)some parents nodes share the same child nodes

Is there any tree structure allows this, or is there any better way to map these data into any kind of graph that can be visualized?